# Where did the function and the variable come from?

Tags: c++, v8

Please sorry, I am JavaScript and TypeScript guy, not a c++ one.

But the JS engine V8 is written in c++ and here is a code piece from [there](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/6.8/samples/hello-world.cc):

```cpp
// Convert the result to an UTF8 string and print it.
v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result);
printf("%s\n", *utf8);
```

In the code above there are two lines. 
First line contains `utf8` function... where does it come from? I didn't see it before in the file and it wasn't imported (or was it)?

Second line contains `utf8` variable (right?), though with `*` modifier which I am not aware of. Where did the variable come from? What is the role of the star modifier?

Sorry for this kind of questions, but at this point I cannot delve into the documentation of one of the most complex languages, which is c++...

Comment: The first line *declares* `utf8`, it introduces a new identifier. So it's normal that you never encounter it earlier in the file. The second line then uses it. These are rather basic and fundamental concepts of C++, and you would better off reading a good book to learn the language. C++ is not a language that can easily be figured out on your own. For all it's strengths it's a very unforgiving and at time unintuitive language.

Comment: how explaining two lines of code help you in the bigger picture? Sure you might get a sense about these two lines of code but that is not going to magically make you understand C++. So are you going to ask for help for every line of C++ you see? I think a better approach for you is to start a quick intro into C++.You can start with something like [c++ for javascript programmers](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+for+javascript+programmers)

Comment: @bolov Thanks for the advice and link! Let's say I am evaluating if it is worth digging deeper by trying to figure out what this simple hello world sample does.

Comment: The first line does not contain a function, and `*` is an operator, not a "modifier" (what do you mean by that?).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks! So a variable declaration can look like a function call expression? Am I right?

Comment: No, function calls cannot look like that. There is an ambiguity in the grammar between variable declarations and function declarations, but not function calls.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for the correction, I knew this must be wrong term. So first line contains a declaration that looks like a function call expression?

Comment: No, it does not look like a function call expression.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev `v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result);` doesn't look like a function call expression. Maybe `utf8(isolate, result);` or `v8::String::Utf8Value 
 foo = utf8(isolate, result);` look like function call expressions, if `utf8` was a declared function.

Comment: To future reviewers: I misclicked Leave Open, sorry. I intended to click Close. I have voted to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`utf8` is not a function, but a variable. The snippet `(isolate, result)` is the *arguments* passed to its constructor.

This could be rewritten as follows to be functionally identical, and in a way that is more familiar to a JavaScript programmer:

```
auto utf8 = v8::String::Utf8Value(isolate, result);
```

where `auto` infers the type of a variable.

As for the `*` in `*utf8`, the meaning of this will depend the implementation. `*` as a prefix operator can be given a user-defined meaning, though usually it has the semantics of "reach into and get the value from," as with raw pointers and things like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::optional`.
I'm not familiar with `v8` personally. You should look for documentation on the `*` operator for the `v8::String::Utf8Value` type, to see exactly what it does.

You should also be very aware that C++ takes a long time to learn, and it's terribly easy to misunderstand or do things very wrong. If you want to commit to learning C++, I would suggest reading a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to get a foundational understanding.

Comment: Wow. This kind of user-defined behavior makes me totally agree with your last paragraph. Thank you so much, for the answer and for the link